# Global variables and threads

Tags: multithreading, synchronization

If I have a global counter and I have two threads that are each incrementing it 100 times in a loop, why is it possible that I can have a value other than 200? I don't see how accessing the variable is nonatomic.

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow.   Please edit your post to tag it with a language.  You should also show your code in your post so we don't have to guess at what you are doing.

Comment: How are you synchronizing this variable which is being accessed and updated by multiple threads?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is because for most environments, incrementing a memory location is not an atomic operation.

The sequence of events would be something like

- The compiler places the value 0 at the memory address 0xABCD
- Thread 1 reads 0xABCD into a register and increments the register value
- Thread 1 is interrupted by Thread 2
- Thread 2 reads the value 0 from the memory address 0xABCD into a register
- Thread 2 increments the value in the register
- Thread 2 writes the value from the register to 0xABCD
- Thread 2 reads the value 1 from 0xABCD, increments the register, and writes back again
- Thread 1 resumes
- Thread 1 writes the value from its register, 1, to 0xABCD, overwriting the value 2 that Thread 2 had previously written there.

To ensure a consistent result, you must make the increment operation atomic.  This is often done by placing a thread lock around the increment operation.  For example, in C# that might look like

```
object mylock = new object();
...
lock (mylock) 
{ 
    myInt++;
}
```

Alternatively, in the .NET environment, one could use Interlocked.Increment

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd78zt0c.aspx

Other environments have similar constructs.

The best reference I have ever come across for threading in the .NET environment (but is a useful read no matter what your environment) is the following

http://www.albahari.com/threading/

Comment: Even if it was, the variable in question is probably not synchronized between the threads.

Comment: @Gray: The question is platform agnostic, but platform specifics come into play (e.g. some compilers require a keyword such as *volatile* to indicate that another thread may change the variable state, while other compilers will re-read the memory location prior to the increment).

Comment: All agreed @Eric. I was just pointing out that the synchronization was probably more the problem than the atomic-ness of ++.