# Unexpected results using threads

Tags: c, pthreads

I'm starting to play with threads (pthreads) and I don't understand how to predict how they work. In other words, I have this really simple program that just increments a variable :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>

int counter = 0;

void *MyThread(void *arg) {
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
        counter++;
    }

    return NULL;
}

int main() {
    pthread_t tid[40];
    int i;
    void *val;
    void *MyThread(void *);

    for (i = 0; i < 40; i++) {
        pthread_create(&tid[i], NULL, MyThread, NULL);
    }

    for (i = 0; i < 40; i++) {
        pthread_join(tid[i], &val);
    }

    printf("Counter = %d\n", counter);
    return 0;
}
```

I don't understand why it gives random results! If I create (and join) 40 threads, how come they don't all finish thier work?

Comment: One assumes that it prints out "counter = " i.e. all threads are done

Comment: You have to make sure you don't change `counter` in more than one thread at the same time. Take a look at pthread_mutex_t.

Comment: Concurrent access to shared resources (the global variable `counter` here) should be protected/synchronised.

Comment: If they have helped you please consider accepting an answer, I am not sure if any of these have solved your issue. If you still have outstanding problems please post so the answers can be amended.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Incrementing is not an atomic operation. As such each thread is likely to corrupt the counter value if they access it simultaneously. If you wish for multiple threads to access a variable at once you must only use atomic operations or wrap the operations in a mutex or semaphore.

The simplest fix you could make, assuming you are using gcc would be to replace the line

```
counter++;
```

with

```
__sync_fetch_and_add(&counter, 1);
```

This will replace the increment with an atomic increment and hopefully the program will execute correctly.

You can find much more information about atomic operations here: http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.1.2/gcc/Atomic-Builtins.html

Answer (score 1):

All your threads are modifying the same global variable (counter). You should read the response to this question

[Global variables and threads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12591132/global-variables-and-threads)

For POSIX threads, you would need to use a mutex and you can find an example on how to here http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v5r3/index.jsp?topic=%2Frzahw%2Frzahwe18rx.htm

Answer (score 0):

They all finish their work. Still, it might not reflected in `counter` due to concurrency issues.
Specifically, it is not defined when or if at all any thread sees updates to `counter` in your example, because you do not synchronize them.

Answer (score 0):

You are using a global variable 'counter'. This variable is being incremented independently without synchronization by all the threads you create.

You cannot have a shared variable(in your case - counter) be manipulated by multiple threads at the same time with out proper synchronization mechanism in place. Otherwise you would have a [race condition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition). which leads to undefined behaviour.

You ought to use pthread mutexes to lock your code which aren't atomic and alter shared variables and which can be executed independently by threads.

You should be aware of [thread safety](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_safety) when writing multithreaded code.